# Magento 2 : Product Table Name in Database

Tags: magento2, product, admin

In my case, I created multiple users and created two or three products from each user from admin panel. So I want to know the name of the table in which username added with product??? please help....

Comment: Default Magento does not have any admin user and product relation. Products are accessible to any admin if he/she have access to catalog product resource.